# complete.cases() working outside but not inside an R function?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I'm wondering why when I run: `iris[complete.cases(iris), ]` it works perfectly fine. But when I do the same thing from the function below, it gives me the error: `colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric`?

p.s. `scale()` works well with data.frames ==> `scale(mtcars)`.

Can this be fixed?

**Here is the function:**

```
standard <- function(data, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE){

data <- if(na.rm) data[complete.cases(data), ]    

data[paste0(names(data), ".s")] <- scale(data, center = center, scale = scale)
return(data)
}
# EXAMPLE:
standard(iris)
```

Comment: I think your problem isn't the `complete.cases` step. It's the `scale()` step

Comment: Try `scale(iris)`

Comment: If you want us to debug it for you, please give us a dput of `immer`, but I believe I've given you what you need to figure out your problem in my answer below.

Comment: What people are trying to lead you to, I think, is that the error message is simply telling you that `scale` expects all columns to be numeric, but (at least) one is not.

Comment: Well, that's going to depend on your data, and what you want to accomplish. For `iris`, there is a column (`iris$Species`)  that is character.

Comment: See my edit below. I think we've answered your question, though (re: why isn't my function working). If you'd like to ask another question about how to get your function to work for data that includes non-numeric columns, give it a shot and ask another question when you run into trouble :)  I'll be happy to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### EDIT:

Yes, the error is thrown by `scale()`, and not earlier. If you want to scale all the numeric columns and leave the other columns as is, you'll need to add a step that extracts the numeric columns, scales them, and then puts them back in. Incidentally, scale can handle NA values, so you can put the `complete.cases()` call after the `scale`.

#### Original Answer:

You can step through this by adding a call to `browser()` inside your function, but I suspect you'll find the error is thrown here:

```
scale(data, center = center, scale = scale)
```

Note from the documentation on `scale()`

> #### Arguments
>
> x        a numeric matrix(like object).

Here's how you'd debug this:

make your function this:

```
standard <- function(data, scale = TRUE, center = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE){
  browser()
  data <- if(na.rm) data[complete.cases(data), ]    

  data[paste0(names(data), ".s")] <- scale(data, center = center, scale = scale)
  return(data)
}
```

Then try to call it with `standard(immer)`
It will open a browser for you to step through each statement in the function. If you do this in RStudio you can see the environment changes in the Environment tab in the upper right window.  Use the command `help` to see how to navigate the browser, but in general, you'll use `n` and/or `s` to step through each statement. `Q` gets you out of the browser, and removing the `browser()` call from your function lets you run it as you would usually.

Comment: It's not base. It must be from a package you have loaded. Because `data(immer)` throws a warning in my console.

Comment: Did you try using the browser?